# jquery performance when using an if/else statement vs two different selector calls

Tags: jquery, performance, dom, if-statement, comparison

I'm curious which of the following (in theory) is better in terms of DOM efficiency. I realize both snippets by themselves could probably be written more concisely but I'm really trying to find out when and where to use and if/else vs. making two different jquery calls.

Snippet 1

```
$('.ele').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('force')) {
    //use it
  } else {
    //hide
  }
});
```

Snippet 2

```
$('.ele.force').click(function() {
  //use it
});

$('.ele.ring').click(function() {
  //hide
});
```

Comment: yes...I should not have thrown in those id's. I'm actually using classes. I will edit.

Comment: changed ID's to classes. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Very good. There is a website that helps you compare efficiency of code snippets, http://jsperf.com/. In this case the first one is faster, you only query the DOM once and only one jQuery object is created.

Comment: gotcha. thnx. I'll check out jsperf.

Comment: wow - big difference! Glad I asked.  http://jsperf.com/sushidub

Comment: Please note that `this.hasClass('force')` should be `$(this).hasClass('force')`. If you want to use the `$(this)` object in your handler more than once , you can cache the object. `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: yup. I think too fast and my logic suffers. Thanks for the catch.

*EDITED

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to avoid conditional statements and use the functions. If we dont know the state at the time of event trigger probably we will end up using conditions in a function.

But here we know that if an `element(.ele)` has class `.force` then the behavior is `//use it` or else it would be `//hide`. So it better to have two separate event handlers.

**Note:** Its very safe to use `.on()/.live()` for this kind of binding because the element might change its state.